# Using sed to change output format

Tags: unix, sed

How can I use sed to change the output format of a text file?

My text file contains and diplays this when I call cat:

```
9/27/2002
9/28/2002
10/1/2002
10/2/2002
10/10/2002
10/11/2002
12/29/2002
1/1/2003
1/2/2003
```

I want it to display like this using sed (with it removing the '/', adding the space, and adding zeroes to the days and months):

```
2002 09 27
2002 09 28
2002 10 01
2002 10 02
2002 10 10
2002 10 11
2002 12 29
2003 01 01
2003 01 02
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You have a good `sed` solution from @chorba, here's how you can do it with awk:

```
awk -F/ '{printf "%d %02d %02d\n", $3, $1, $2}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use capture groups. The first part changes the order of the numbers, the second adds zeros to the second columns, the third adds zeros to the third.

```
sed -e 's=\(.*\)/\(.*\)/\(.*\)=\3 \1 \2=' -e 's= \(.\) = 0\1 =' -e 's= \(.\)$= 0\1='
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept a non-sed solution to the problem (why limit yourself to sed?), here's the canonical *perl* solution, in addition to the *awk* one:

```
perl -laF/ -ne 'printf "%s %02d %02d\n", @F[2,0,1]'
```

**Explanation:**

```
-a    auto-splits the input into the array @F
-l    strips newline on input
-F/   defines input delimiter to split on
-n    loops over all lines of input
-e    perl expression to run in each loop pass

printf       self explanatory
```

You may pass your input either as a file name(s) following the perl call, or via standard input.